# Swipe to delete vs. edit button tapped on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I set up my viewController to use the edit button in the way Apple recommends:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When the user taps the edit button, it causes the `setEditing:animated:` method to trigger. In this method, I add or remove a "new row" depending on the `editing` value (i.e. a row the user can tap to add a new item).

When the user swipes across a cell (while not in edit mode), it also calls the `setEditing:animated:`, which causes my code to add this "new row" incorrectly. It should only show this new row when the entire viewController is in edit mode (i.e. when the edit button is tapped).

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you implement `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`, the behavior of the method calls will change...

It will no longer call `setEditing:animated:`, you must handle all editing change logic inside the above two methods. As a side effect of this, `self.editing` will no longer be `YES` when a swipe gesture is invoked. This is because the `setEditing:animated:` is responsible for setting `self.editing = YES`.

Comment: can you change the image of delete?

Comment: You just need to call super inside willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and the UITableViewController will set editing for you. See my answer for how to differentiate between edit button tap and swiping on a row.

Comment: In my experience, in swift 4/ios 12, just implementing them did not change the behavior. I had to set a flag like the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`.  From the documentation:

> This method is called when the user swipes horizontally across a row; as a 
>       consequence, the table view sets its editing property to `YES` (thereby entering editing 
>       mode) and displays a Delete button in the row identified by indexPath. In this "swipe to 
>       delete" mode the table view does not display any insertion, deletion, and reordering 
>       controls. This method gives the delegate an opportunity to adjust the application's user 
>       interface to editing mode. When the table exits editing mode (for example, the user taps 
>       the Delete button), the table view calls `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`.

In `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`, set a flag that editing mode was triggered using swipe to delete.  Then, in `setEditing:animated:`, check the flag to see if editing mode was triggered normally or using swipe to delete and perform some action based on that check.  Lastly, reset the flag in `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` so that the default action will be performed when the edit button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your "new row" is about, but you could attach your edit button to a helper method that sets a flag before calling setEditing, and there you can check if the said flag is set and behave accordingly. Then clear the flag at the end of the method.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without overriding the edit button's behavior? I'd like to use Apple's recommendation if possible. (I clarified the question)

Comment: Is adding the new row standard behavior anyway? I thought a "+" or "Add" button would be the consistent way to do this. If a user needs to press edit to add new items, this calls for lots of support mails. :-)

Comment: see the Contacts app for adding an email/phone

Comment: @Senseful: That editing is a complete change of a the view, but I see the point. I think a flag and a custom button is the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Senseful u have to override setEditing:animated: method. or even u can set flag in this method as Eiko has suggested.

or other way is

u implement custom naviagtion bar. in that case u need image of Navigation bar and 2 buttons above it.
add target to that button and implement functionality as your need

Answer (score 0):

The table enters edit mode both when the user taps the edit button and also when swiping on a cell. To differentiate between these two cases you can override `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` (remember to call super or editing mode won't be entered) and store the index path in a property. Override `setEditing` and you can check the property and only add your insert row if it is nil (i.e. when the user isn't swiping).

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) NSIndexPath *tableViewEditingRowIndexPath;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.tableViewEditingRowIndexPath = indexPath;
    [super tableView:tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // calls setEditing:YES
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [super tableView:tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // calls setEditing:NO
    self.tableViewEditingRowIndexPath = nil;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if(self.tableViewEditingRowIndexPath){
         // we are swiping
         return;
    }
    if(editing){
        // insert row for adding
    }
    else{
        // remove row for adding
    }
}
```